# Setting states in a react redux constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to set the state for two separate uPort logins in react redux. I have tried to do it below however I am getting an error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this.props.actions.connectUportDoc
>   is not a function

I want to basically create an if else statement. If the patient button is pressed push to confirmLoginPatient. If doctor button is pressed, push to confirmLoginDoctor.

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // this.connectUport = this.connectUport.bind(this)
    this.connectUportDoc = this.connectUportDoc.bind(this)
    this.connectUportPatient = this.connectUportPatient.bind(this)

    uportConnect.onResponse(ConnectReqID).then((res) => {
      console.log('res.payload')
      console.log(res.payload)
      this.props.actions.connectUportDoc(uportConnect.state)
      this.props.history.push('/confirmLoginDoctor')
    })

    uportConnect.onResponse(ConnectReqID).then((res) => {
      console.log('res.payload')
      console.log(res.payload)
      this.props.actions.connectUportPatient(uportConnect.state)
      this.props.history.push('/confirmLoginPatient')
    })
  }

  connectUportDoc() {
    const reqObj = {
      requested: ['name', 'phone', 'country', 'avatar', 'email'],
      notifications: true,
    }
    console.log(reqObj)
    uportConnect.requestDisclosure(reqObj, ConnectReqID)
  }

  connectUportPatient() {
    const reqObj = {
      requested: ['name', 'phone', 'country', 'avatar', 'email'],
      notifications: true,
    }
    console.log(reqObj)
    uportConnect.requestDisclosure(reqObj, ConnectReqID)
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <a onClick={this.connectUportDoc.bind(this)}>Doctor Login</a>
       <a onClick={this.connectUportPatient.bind(this)}>Patient Login</a>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    uport: state.login.uport,
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return { actions: bindActionCreators(AppActions, dispatch) }
}

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(Login)
)
```

Comment: typo: `this.props.actions.connectUportDoc(uportConnect.state)`

Comment: can you paste the complete component? What is `actions`? Why are you expecting it in `props`? All these questions cannot be answered with the posted segment of code.

Comment: Component is now complete @Vishal Sharma